# Regex of every first char and any capital in the word

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having troubles with REGEX trying to build one that would retrieve the first letter of a word and any other Capital letter of that word and each first letter including the any Capital letter in the same word

```
"WelcomeBack to NorthAmerica a great place to be" = WBTNAAGPTB
"WelcomeBackAgain to NorthAmerica it's nice here" = WBATNAINH
"Welcome to the NFL, RedSkins-Dolphins play today" = WTTNFLRSDPT
```

tried this juus to get the first 2 matches:

```
/([A-Z])|\b([a-zA-Z])/g
```

Any help is welcomed, thanks

Comment: Is it JavaScript?

Comment: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573817/get-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-using-regex

Comment: I have seen regex formulated differently for each language, so I just included the lang I'm using. But the question is mainly REGEX

Comment: [`str.replace(/\b[a-z]/g, w => w.toUpperCase()).match(/[A-Z]/g).join('')`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/Las014xh/)

Comment: Thanks, @Sampad, but "?<=" (Look behind) is not supported in JavaScript

Comment: `\b` won't work because of `it's`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a regex that will match all uppercase letters and those lowercase letters that appear at the start of the string or after a whitespace:

```js
var re = /[A-Z]+|(?:^|\s)([a-z])/g; 
var strs = ["WelcomeBack to NorthAmerica a great place to be", "WelcomeBackAgain to NorthAmerica it's nice here", "Welcome to the NFL, RedSkins-Dolphins play today"];
for (var s of strs) {
  var res = "";
  while((m = re.exec(s)) !== null) {
    if (m[1]) {
       res += m[1].toUpperCase();
    } else {
      res += m[0];
    }
  }
  console.log(res);
}
```

Here, `[A-Z]+|(^|\s)([a-z])` matches multiple occurrences of:

- `[A-Z]+` - 1 or more uppercase ASCII letters
- `|` - or
- `(?:^|\s)`  - start of string (`^`) or a whitespace (`\s`)
- `([a-z])` - Group 1: one lowercase ASCII letter.

Comment: The code could be simplified a tiny bit by also capturing the uppercase characters, which means that the `if` statement can be removed as the  the loop will simply collect all captured content into a string (`m.slice(1).find(x=>x)`), followed by uppercasing the whole result. This will cut 4 lines out of the `while` loop and thus the `for` loop will be almost half the size.

Comment: Thanks, @wiktor, it works like a charm. And great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let s = "WelcomeBack to NorthAmerica a great place to be";
s = s.match(/([A-Z])|(^|\s)(\w)/g);    // -> ["W","B"," t", " N"...]
s = s.join('');                        // -> 'WB t N...'
s = s.replace(/\s/g, '');              // -> 'WBtN...'
return s.toUpperCase();                // -> 'WBT ...'
```

`/(?:([A-Z])|\b(\w))/g` matches every uppercase letter `([A-Z])` OR `|` every letter `(\w)` that follows the start of the string `^` or a whitespace `\s`.

(I couldn't get the whitespace to not be captured for some reason, hence the `replace` step. Surely there are better tricks, but this is the most readable I find.)

Comment: If that were that easy, the whole code could be a one-liner. I already tried this approach before posting my answer. The second sample string should return `WBATNAINH`, and [your code returns `WBATNAISNH`](https://jsfiddle.net/x5vga5s1/).

Comment: You don't need to wrap the capturing groups in another group to make the OR work. It works the same without it.

Comment: *I couldn't get the whitespace to not be captured for some reason* - the reason is that JS regex engine does not support lookbehinds :(

Comment: How weird.. I mean you can NOT capture other stuff, right? Why does whitespace require lookbehinds?

Comment: @HumanCatfood it's not "whitespace", really. You can very well not capture stuff using `(?:)` however a `regex.exect` will return _everything_ matched at index zero. This includes non-capturing groups. Captured groups are then placed in the rest of the indeces in the returned array. The only way to _exclude_ stuff from being matched is to use a zero-length match - those will not be matched and hence not returned at index zero. A lookbehind is a zero-length match, however, JS does not support it. You can emulate it by reversing the string and the regex, then using a lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex as : `/\b[a-z]|[A-Z]+/g;`

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>JavaScript String match() Method</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var str = "WelcomeBack to NorthAmerica a great place to be";
         var re = /\b[a-z]|[A-Z]+/g;
         var found = str.match( re );
         found.forEach(function(item, index) {
            found[index] = item.toUpperCase();
        });
          document.write(found.join('')); 
      </script>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try with `WelcomeBackAgain to NorthAmerica it's nice here` and - after some editing - you will get to a solution closer to mine or HumanCatford's.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it will also take care of whitespaces

```
str = str.match(/([A-Z])|(^|\s)(\w)/g);
str = str.join('');
str=str.replace(/ /g,'');
return str.toUpperCase();
```